# Flatten Hierachy Rollup using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT and am looking to solve the following problem. I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
   <Entry>
      <CName>CCXXX</CName>
      <CCH_Summary>Marketing</CCH_Summary>
      <CCH_Rollup_1>Marketing Group</CCH_Rollup_2>
      <CCH_Rollup_2>Marketing (COR)</CCH_Rollup_2>
      <CCH_Rollup_3>Cost of Revenue</CCH_Rollup_3>
      <CCH_Rollup_4>Total Cost Centre</CCH_Rollup_4>
   </Entry>
   <Entry>
      <CName>CCXXX</CName>
      <CCH_Summary>Finance</CCH_Summary>
      <CCH_Rollup_1>Finance Ret</CCH_Rollup_2>
      <CCH_Rollup_2>Finance Acct (COR)</CCH_Rollup_2>
      <CCH_Rollup_3>Cost of Revenue</CCH_Rollup_3>
      <CCH_Rollup_4>Total Cost Centre</CCH_Rollup_4>
   </Entry>
</Data>
```

What I am trying to do is to get all distinct values from CCH_Rollup_1 and  get the corresponding sibling CCH_Rollup_2. Then I need all distinct CCH_Rollup_2 values and get their sibling CCH_Rollup_3 and so on. Basically - flatten the "hierarchy" into 2 columns.

The output that I'm expecting is this:

```
Marketing,Marketing Group
Marketing Group,Marketing (COR)
Marketing (COR), Cost of Revenue
Finance,Finance Ret
Finance Ret, Finance Acct
Finance Acct, Cost of Revenue
Cost of Revenue,Total Cost Centre    
Total Cost Centre,
```

My first approach was to use distinct-values(), however that doesn't really allow me to return the sibling as position() is reset.

```
<xsl:variable name="rootnode" select="/"/>

    <xsl:template match="//Data">        
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//CCH_Rollup_1)">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />,<xsl:value-of select="$rootnode/Entry[position()]/CCH_Rollup_2" />
        </xsl:for-each>
```

The second attempt approach I tried is assigning an ID to each entry, and using that to return the sibling. However, it doesn't seem to be returning anything.

```
<xsl:variable name="rootnode" select="/"/> 

<!-- build first column -->

<xsl:key name="CCH" match="//Data/Entry/CCH_Rollup[*]/text()" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="//Data/Entry/text()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('CCH',.)[1])]">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />,<xsl:value-of select="$rootnode/Entry[position()]/CCH_Rollup_2" />
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

What am I doing wrong? What is a good way to approach this?

Comment: Can you show the exact output you want from your input, as I am guessing you don't want to literally output `aa`, `bb`, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Is the order of the rows in the output important?

Comment: The order is not important, as long as it's only distinct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order is not important, you can make use of `distinct-values` here. Try this template

```
<xsl:template match="Data">        
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//Entry/*[not(self::CName)]/concat(., ',', following-sibling::*[1]))">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

In fact, you don't need `xsl:for-each` here. A single `xsl:value-of` will do

```
<xsl:template match="Data">        
    <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(//Entry/*[not(self::CName)]/concat(., ',', following-sibling::*[1]))" separator="&#10;" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's the one, Tim! Thanks!